# Laravel Nova: Is there a way to change text of "Cancel" button?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am trying to change the text of the "Cancel" button to "Back" since it fits the button's behavior better. Is there a way to do this? I tried finding the element in the DOM and changing its textContent but it didn't work as expected. (This is the button that appears when creating a new Resource).

[image]

Comment: Which button you are trying to update? `javascript` Alert popup??

Comment: https://imgur.com/eFUOtx8

Comment: it seems a js library. You need to check its document to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

[Localization](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/localization.html#overview)

You can customise the `en.json` file under `resources/lang/vendor/nova` translation directory.

Edit `"Cancel": "Cancel"` to `"Cancel": "Back"`.

Note: This will update **all** the places where the Cancel has been used.